# Javascript Date Function Setting and getting

Tags: javascript, function, date, set

Hi I am trying to set the day to the 2nd and retrieve it in javascript. I have tried d.getDay(d.setDay(2)) as well as other things.

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    document.write("<br /><span style = \"color: " + 
                   getRandomColor() +"\">My Birthdate is: " 
                   + monthNames[d.getMonth(d.setMonth(0))] + 
                   d.getDay(d.setDay(1)) + "</span>");
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is `monthNames`?

Comment: The months come out fine. it searches my array and retrieves the proper month. It's just my setdate/getdate i try to set for 2nd but it return undefined

Comment: Try moment.js. It has nice features to interact with date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JavaScript Date Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp), there's no `setDay` method, and `getDay` returns the weekday number (0-6) instead of the day number (1-31). The correct method to get the day number is `getDate` and the correct method to set the day number is `setDate`. You need to change this

```
d.getDay(d.setDay(1))
```

to this

```
d.getDate(d.setDate(2))
```

so your code should be as below

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    document.write("<br /><span style = \"color: " + 
                   getRandomColor() +"\">My Birthdate is: " 
                   + monthNames[d.getMonth(d.setMonth(0))] + 
                   d.getDate(d.setDate(2)) + "</span>");
</script>
```